# Validating phone number in Java using twilio

Tags: java, twilio

I want to verify if a phone number is valid and what is the type of phone number [cell/landline]. How can this be achieved in Java using twilio?

Thanks.

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

For this you can use the [Lookup API](https://www.twilio.com/lookup). Take a look through the documentation on how to [use the Lookup API in Java](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups).

Here's a quick example though. You'll need to install the [Java helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install), then try this code:

```
import com.twilio.sdk.LookupsClient;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.lookups.PhoneNumber;

public class Example {

  // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/user/account
  public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "{{ account_sid }}";
  public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "{{ auth_token }}";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws TwilioRestException {
    LookupsClient client = new LookupsClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    PhoneNumber number = client.getPhoneNumber("+15108675309", true);

    System.out.println(number.getType());
    System.out.println(number.getCarrierName());
  }
}
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks a ton!!! It worked. 1 question- Is there a way where we can send multiple numbers in one request?

Comment: I'm afraid not, the API is one number at a time.

Comment: Okay..Well Thanks a ton for your inputs :)

Comment: No problem. It'd be great if you could mark the answer as correct so that other people can see that it helped. Thanks!